# Multiple line search in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to search for 3 different key words across different files in Notepad++

1. "//approved" OR
2. "//  approved" OR
3. Refer to image:

[image]

Note that the 3rd string is distributed in 3 new consecutive lines

How do I do that in Notepad++, please help.

Answer (score 3):

#### I would like to search for 3 different key words across different files

- Menu "Search" > "Find in Files" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `//approved|// approved|/\*\r\napproved\r\n\*/`.
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Find All"

Notes:

- Use `\r\n` for Windows EOLs
- Use `\n` for Unix/OSX EOLs
- Use `\r` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

  [image]

**Test.txt**:

```
foo
//approved
bar
// approved
foo
/*
approved
*/
bar
```

**Find results**:

```
Search "//approved|// approved|/\*\r\napproved\r\n\*/" (5 hits in 2 files)
  F:\test\notepad regex answer template nl.txt (2 hits)
  Line 5:  - Set "Find what" to `//approved|// approved|/\*\r\napproved\r\n\*/`.
  Line 5:  - Set "Find what" to `//approved|// approved|/\*\r\napproved\r\n\*/`.
  F:\test\test.txt (3 hits)
  Line 2: //approved
  Line 4: // approved
  Line 6: /*
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)