# Remove a line containing a word and the previous line

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm editing a HTML file on Notepad++, and the problem is that is a very big file, and I want to remove some unnecessary lines to work on it.
The following code appears a lot in it, at the start of every page. I'd like to remove it. I know how to remove a entire line containing a given word, i.e., to remove only the line containing "jardinagem", i'd type in the find field: . *jardinagem. * (without the spaces)

But the problem is this specific code is 3, sometimes 4 lines. So, how do I do it?
There are other similar types of lines I want to remove, if I understand how to remove these ones, the others I can follow the example.
Thanks in advance.

```
<DIV  style="z-index:25; position:absolute; left:10PX; top:0PX; width:558PX; height:21PX; " class="adornment10" >
<table width="553PX" border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td NOWRAP class="fontColor11" >JARDINAGEM COMPANY</td></tr></table>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple line search in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/1205345/multiple-line-search-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Do this replacement in Notepad++.

Find what : `<DIV.*?JARDINAGEM.*?</DIV>\r\n`
Replace with : (nothing - leave blank)
Check : "Regular expression" and ". matches newline"
Click "Replace All".

Explanation :

- `.*?` will match any string of characters, the `?` means not-greedy match
- `\r\n` means an end of line on Windows (Linux : `\n`, Mac : `\r`)
- ". matches newline" will let matches to cross the line boundary.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.